# Drupal Form -- no output

Tags: php, drupal

I have the following code on a page in the body section.

```
<?php
function test_myform($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item', 
    '#title' => t('A form with nothing but a textfield'),
  );
  // This is the first form element. It's a textfield with a label, "Name"
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Name'),
  );
  return $form;
}
function test_page() {
  return drupal_get_form('test_myform');
}

test_page();

?>
```

This does not return anything. Nothing happens. The page is blank. What am I missing? Can anyone give me hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO and Drupal Form API (Nice to call it FAPI but you know Internet memes). 
First, let us know the Drupal version you need to get this form working, and where you need to get this shown.

See http://drupal.org/node/751826 for a nice startup tutorial. Don't forget that it's for Drupal 6.

If you want to show the form in a specific page, (/myform for example), you have to hook_menu() to register your path. Then you don't have to print/echo the form as long as you have drupal_get_form as your callback function.

The easiest way to get a form up is by putting the PHP code in a block (nobody says its easier - just my thoughts.)
You won't need arguments to **build** the form.

```
function test_myform(){
$form['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item', 
    '#title' => t('A form with nothing but a textfield'),
  );
  // This is the first form element. It's a textfield with a label, "Name"
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Name'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Now you have a form array that can be called from test_myform(). Cool huh ?

use this to display the form.

```
return drupal_get_form('my_form');
```

Then you will see that this is the same code as you have tried already. That's where the version is useful. This works in D6 but no longer in D7. 
Now try this:

```
return drupal_render(drupal_get_form('my_form'));
```

See ?

Note that this code is to be used in a php block. It's not recommended to have enabled php filter module but you have to do that, to get the form up.

The best way is defining your own block or menu callback to get the form up. 
See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7 to see how to register a path. Now, note that you will need to make the `test_myform()` function to accept arguments as your code. Page callback should be drupal_get_form and no need of `drupal_render()` to get the form shown.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually outputting anything. You create the `$form` array or object in the function, and return it, but you aren't echoing or outputting anything in any of your other code.

UPDATE

A quick look at the docs for this function seem to indicate that the form markup is returned by the function. So if you leave out the test page function, try this:

```
echo drupal_get_form('test_myform');
```

Basically, `drupal_get_form` is returning the form content, and it's up to you to output it in some way.

Comment: So how would I be able to actually output this form? Actually make it so that the user fills in the "description" and "name". I've been searching this for a couple of hours to no avail.

Comment: Do you have API documentation for Drupal forms? Because it doesn't look like you're doing anything but creating an array.

Comment: I've been taking examples from the Drupal website. This is all they say. Very high level explanations as opposed to practical examples such as a full working example. I'm new to both php and drupal but I've never had this much difficulty learning on the fly.

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing that does is print the "type" of the form is Array but I do appreciate the thought.

Comment: @user1396465 `drupal_get_form()` returns a [render array](http://drupal.org/node/930760); you need to run it through [`render()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/render/7) to get the HTML output: `echo render(drupal_get_form('test_myform'));`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
change the function line as below:
function test_myform() { //no need to add any arguments if you are not using


secondly either directly print the form using the line below
print drupal_get_form('test_myform');

or use the function to return the form html and print it
print test_page();
```

Comment: Don't know why this is downvoted but this is correct if you are going to put this code in a block. Upvoted.